Universal way to check for empty/uninitialized RAW values
I am hoping to find a  universal way to test "initial"/uninitialized values of RAW type (potentially other binary too). ABAP initial value article says there are no initial values for certain data types and RAW is one of them.
My requirement is to read by by empty UUID (RAW data type) and I found some ways to do it, but they are not compatible across different technologies and in some cases are even contradictory.
I am working in SAP CAR with /DMF/PRC table (looking for non location specific price for PROD_ID empty LOC_ID), but to make my example more accessible I've changed my example using BUT000-PARTNER_GUID.
Test data
types: begin of typ_result,
     key1 type i,                   "Mostly irrelevant field
     uuid type but000-partner_guid, "RAW(16)
   end of typ_result,
   typ_t_result type standard table of typ_result with default key.
data(lt_data) = value typ_t_result( (  key1 = 1 ) ). "Create a table with 1 record that has empty UUID

ABAP code is fairly forgiving and initially makes sense
read table lt_data transporting no fields with key uuid = 0.
read table lt_data transporting no fields with key uuid = ' '.
loop at lt_data transporting no fields where uuid is initial.

ABAP SQL in ABAP code does not allow uuid = 0 and uuid = ' ', however the following 3 work
select * from @lt_data as data where bintohex( uuid ) = '00000000000000000000000000000000' into table @data(lt_sql_res).
select * from @lt_data as data where uuid = hextobin( '00000000000000000000000000000000' ) appending table @lt_sql_res.
select * from @lt_data as data where uuid is initial appending table @lt_sql_res.

ABAP SQL in CDS view prohibits uuid is initial because "Raw has no initial value" (syntax error), only leaving bintohex / hextobin as usable options. These aren't great as zero short or too many will cause mismatch or syntax errors (depending on which way you do it).
I'm using ABAP 7.56/7.57, however answers regarding any version would be nice.

You can also check the IS INITIAL value in ABAP code. For example: IF lt_data IS INITIAL. or CHECK lt_data IS INITIAL. If you are talking about a specific element, you can LOOP or read that element. Maybe lin_exists( ).

You're right. After messing around for so long it seemed so obvious I forgot to mention it. I will include it in the question for the sake of clarity

Highly unlikely you will find a universal way between such heterogenous technologies like CDS, classic ABAP and ABAPSql which must conform to differents RDBMS rules and be truly DB-agnostic. And what is the use of such universal way? You will not be able to fully push the code to DB on all frameworks like on HANA

The use is less ambiguity. Having 3 techs all named after ABAP having different rules on this isn't very intuitive. If that method happened to be an alternative to hextobin( ) it could also save the effort of having of counting digits.

Have you tried a combination of built-in functions like
SELECT 
   partner
 FROM 
  BUT000
 where length( ltrim( bintohex( partner_guid ), '0' ) ) = 0

This works fine, and you don't have to worry about number of zeros (:

Thanks. It's definitely an interesting approach. I wouldn't personally use it, because my team wouldn't like reading that, but it does work on either length which is nice.

@Zero The only caveat is that bintohex is not available on earlier releases... (big oops!) I have ECC on HANA, ABAP component version 7.50 - the function is missing ): Quick search in ABAP help 7.50 showed that there is no workaround for that as RAW types are non-castable, and there are no bitwise comparisons...

I was thinking of using host expressions such as where raw_field = @( value #( ) ), but then i realised that your requirement is not ABAP but CDS views which makes it impossible... Unless you move the condition out of CDS into a consuming program. But in this case IS INITIAL also works starting from version 7.53...
